# Is there any object which is not a float but can be accepted as a float in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib

I'm working on building a Mysql database with some experiment results. Usually, the values I want to write into tables are float, but sometimes they are not. It's like:

```
         exp1    exp2    exp3    exp4

gene1       0     1.2     1.3     N/A
gene2     2.2     2.0     3.3     1.9
gene3     N/A     5.5     5.2     6.9
```

For some reasons, values of experiment are not available, and are not 0. I wanted the type of column that stores these values to be float, but it failed because there were 'N/A's.

Of course I can use Varchar but one more problem came up when I used python to retrieve some values and wanted to draw a graph with them using matplotlib.pyplot, it failed again because these 'N/A' strings couldn't be converted into float.

Please help me with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why cant you make the column `NULL`? `NULL` is absence of any value and all programming languages will gracefully handle it.

Comment: what will null be on a graph? I don't think i will be accepted by the plotting function i am using. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Skywrath, you really should investigate your ability to handle null as thoroughly as you can, because it really is the correct answer. Null is not a value, it's a marker that indicates the absence of a value.  MySQL functions like AVG() handle null correctly, also, so that, for example, the average of 3, 6, and null = 4.5; you wont get that kind of truth from any other solution. +1

Comment: @skywarth: the null representation in graph depends on the your library and how you pass null values to graph

Answer (score 0):

While retrieving with `select` you can apply `cast` on columns to return a numeric value.

```
mysql> select cast( 'n/a' as decimal ) na_to_num;
+-----------+
| na_to_num |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
```

Other alternative is inserting `NULL` when a value is not available. But you can't cast `NULL` to numeric value. You need explicit check for `NULL` and return a `0` on them.

```
mysql> select cast( ifnull(null,0) as decimal ) as null_to_num;
+-------------+
| null_to_num |
+-------------+
|           0 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But when i plot these values on a graph, nulls are the same as 0 in this way. I need to distinguish n/a and 0. I have talked with my boss, he said it would be ok to give n/a the value of -1, cuz these values can't be negative. what i need is to note the users in advance that '-1' is N/A, which is the cheapest way I can do about it. Thank you anyway, the 'cast' function is amazing. I will look into it.